# Is there a proper way to make factory boy connect to the test database

Tags: python, django, testing, factory-boy

I'm experiencing a very annoying error on my project's test suites, because factory boy is running every test case on the main/default database, instead of running the queries on the proper test database.

I tried adding the Meta class configuration to a factory class (as recomended in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550262/how-to-specify-the-database-for-factory-boy)), but as soon as I try to run the django test suite, the application throws an error stating that the connection to the test database does not exist.

I would very much appreciate any help, since the documentation is not clear at all about this situation.

My settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": 'DB_NAME',
        "USER": 'DB_USER',
        "PASSWORD": 'DB_PSSWD',
        "HOST": 'DB_HOST',
        "PORT": 3306,
        "TEST":{
            "NAME": 'TEST_DB_NAME',
        },
        "OPTIONS": {
            "init_command": "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'; SET foreign_key_checks = 0;",
        },
    }
}
```

my factory.py:

```
import factory

class CustomModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.CustomModel
        database = 'TEST_DB_NAME'
        django_get_or_create = ('nu_cnpj',)

    nm_razao_social = factory.Faker(locale='pt_BR', provider='company')
    nu_cnpj = factory.Faker(locale='pt_BR', provider='company_id')
```

my model.py:

```
from django.db import models

class CustomModel(models.Model):
    nu_cnpj = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    nm_razao_social = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
```

The error:

```
python manage.py test flux.tests.test_data_leak_main_db --keepdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 172, in ensure_defaults
    conn = self.databases[alias]
KeyError: 'TEST_DB_NAME'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
    raise ConnectionDoesNotExist("The connection %s doesn't exist" % alias)
django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection TEST_DB_NAME doesn't exist
```

Comment: Just curious, how did you figure out it was using your main database? Tests will always create a separate test database.

Comment: I discovered it was leaking data by cleaning up my default database and running the main test suite from django right after. Then, when checking my default db after the test suite was run, there were factory made records on the my db.

Answer (score 0):

Finally my teammates and I were able to track down exactly what factory implementation was generating this weird behaviour.There was a factory call inside a factory class definition, which led to a data insert during import fase (which is prior to the creation of the test database from the default db). Therefore, objects from factories were being inserted in the default db which was the only one available for the ORM.

The faulty implementation was like the following:

```py
import factory

class CustomModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.CustomModel
        database = 'TEST_DB_NAME'
        django_get_or_create = ('nu_cnpj',)

    nm_razao_social = factory.Faker(locale='pt_BR', provider='company')
    nu_cnpj = factory.Faker(locale='pt_BR', provider='company_id')

    class Params:
        test = factory.Trait(
            nm_razao_social='Test',
        )

class ForeignRelatedCustomModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    name = factory.Faker(locale='pt_BR', provider='first_name')
    address = factory.Faker('address')
    status = factory.Faker('pystr')
    fk = factory.SubFactory('CustomModelFactory')

    class Params:
        test = factory.Trait(
            fk=CustomModelFactory(test=True), # this line resulted in a factory call during import, inserting data into the 'default' database instead of the test replica db, during the execution of `python manage.py test`
            name='Test'
        )
```